# While loop: Need assistance

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, boolean

I can't find the problem that causes my while loop not to work.

When I run the program and press a radio button, I get this error code:

Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement

Here is my loop:

```
int i = 1;
boolean x;
//for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
do{ 
    warning.setText("          FEL!");          
    i++;
    while(x == false);{

    if(e.getSource() == buttonOK){

        if(buttonDollar.isSelected() == false){
            x = false;
        }
        if(buttonEuro.isSelected() == false){
            x = false;
        }
        if(buttonPund.isSelected() == false){
            x = false;
        }
        if(buttonKrona.isSelected() == false){
            x = false;
        }
        break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a `while` clause to complete a `do-while` statement.  If you want to loop forever, then use `do { ... } while (true)`.  Or just `while (true) { ... }`.  P.S.  What language is this?

Comment: @rajansoft1:  Depending on the language, should initialize to the default value.

Comment: @zimdanen can you please add language tag to it, it might help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The semicolon in `while(x == false);{` will almost certainly cause a disaster.

Comment: I am trying to check all radio buttons in a loop. If all the radio buttons are unchecked, a message will appear that says " FEL " which means "error" in swedish.
The code is in Java

Comment: Then why loop? Seems you have a fixed number of known checkboxes. They're not in an array. You also aren't really doing anything with the information. This code is taking something trivial and wrapping it in a layer of unnecessary complexity that you're clearly not comfortable with yet. Also, I doubt you're actually able to run the program and are only getting the syntax error after you press the button.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the syntax for "while" element

From the sun site (I am guessing that this is java)

```
do {
    statement(s)
} while (expression);
```

Comment: Okay, and what does "statement(s)" look like?

Comment: @user2422314:  `statement(s)` is the code you have in your sample between `do {` and the closing `}`.

Comment: you need to know what the word "statement" means in order to be able to write code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a closing curly brace before the while

```
do{ 
warning.setText("          FEL!");         
i++; 
}while(x == false);
```

Comment: while(x == false);{  Have you tried removing this curly brace after this while statement in addition to adding the one before? It looks as if the one after the while has no reason to be there. maybe try it like this: do{ 
    warning.setText("          FEL!");          
    i++;}
    while(x == false);

Answer (score 0):

The whole structure is all wrong, you're looking to do something very simple:

```
if(e.getSource() == buttonOK)
{
    if( !buttonDollar.isSelected() && !buttonEuro.isSelected()
        && !buttonPund.isSelected() && !buttonKrona.isSelected() )
    {
        warning.setText("          FEL!");          
    }
}
```

From a UI perspective, it's better to ensure that one radio button is always selected (as this is what your users will likely expect).